# unable to assign number to a field

Tags: apex, business-logic

I have a requirement where I need to check if **Revision_Number__c** number field is blank. If its blank than assign 1 else increment by 1. Following is what I tried.

```
    if(quoteLink.Revision_Number__c.isBlank)
    {
        quoteLink.Revision_Number__c=1;        
    }  
    else
    {
        clonedQuteLink.Revision_Number__c+=1;
    }
```

It works if the **Revision_Number__c** already has some values. If its blank then an error about derefencing null values appears. Please guide. Thanks

Comment: Is `Revision_Number__c` an integer field, a formula, a look-up or is it a text field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for null first and treat the blanks as zeros.

Try this:

```
if(quoteLink.Revision_Number__c!=null)
    {
        if(quoteLink.Revision_Number__c > 0)
           clonedQuteLink.Revision_Number__c+=1;
    }  
    else
    {
         quoteLink.Revision_Number__c=1;       

    }
```

Comment: Two things here: (1) `null <op> var` is difficult to read compared to `var <op> null`, unless your native language is a right-to-left language. Consider revising. We don't write `1 = x` to assign 1 to x, we write `x = 1`. Nor do we say, in English, "if null is Revision_Number__c", but instead say "if Revision_Number__c is null". It keeps the "language" consistent. (2) See my deleted answer on not using if-else to reduce code complexity and providing easier code coverage.

Comment: I tried with if(quoteLink.Revision_Number__c!=null) and also as if(null!=quoteLink.Revision_Number__c). Both didn't work if field has no values. Else its working if field has already a value which it increments. Thanks

Comment: pepefloyd @sfdcfox I solved my problem. THere seemed to be some problem in my code. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
if(quoteLink.Revision_Number__c.isEmpty() == false )

{
    clonedQuteLink.Revision_Number__c+=1;

}  

else

{
     quoteLink.Revision_Number__c=1;        
}
```

If this doesn't work, you may need to add a try-catch block to trap a null-pointer exception whenever Revision_Number__c isEmpty or null.

Comment: thnaks @crmprogdev        if(clonedQuteLink.Revision_Number__c != null) did the trick